# How to generate JSON data from NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I'm new to Swift and I am trying to generate JSON data from an `NSDictionary`

Here's my code:

```
func metricsToJson() {
        if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(metricsData, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error) {
            if let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                println(json)
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]
I'm not sure why this isn't working, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some mighty impressive code you've got there.  (Paste the code into your question, highlight it, then press the `{}` button above the editing window.  Don't embed images of code, even if you manage to do it correctly.)

Comment: Sorry about that. I wanted to show the screenshot so you could see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, it may help to solve your problem.

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(metricsData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSArray

for var i = 0; i<jsonResult.count; ++i {

    var dictResult = jsonResult.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary
    // your code...
}
```